# How to replace a string in one file if a pattern present in another file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a data file `A.txt` (field separator = \t) :

```
Well    Well Type   Well Name   Dye Target  
A1      Unknown     HIGH-001    FAM ViroFAM                 
A1      Unknown     HIGH-001    HEX ViroHEX
```

And a template file `B.txt`:

```
kit
Software Version = NOVA_v1
Date And Time of Export = 07/02/2020 13:44:11 UTC
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
,taq,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
,taq,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

And I want to print replace the value after the `=`in the second line of `B.txt` with `VIRO_v1`, but only when the pattern `ViroHEX` is present in the 5th column of `A.txt`.

In order to do that I start something like :

```
awk -F'\t' '
  FNR==NR{ a[NR]=$2; next }
  $1=="Software Version"{ print $0,"VIRO_v1"; next }
  1
' B.txt FS=" =" B.txt > result.txt
```

But I didn't figure it out the part with `A.txt`. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' '
  NR==FNR{ if ($5=="ViroHEX"){ viro=1 } next }
  viro && $1=="Software Version"{ $2="VIRO_v1" }
  1
' A.txt FS=" = " OFS=" = " B.txt > result.txt
```

This replaces the second field (`NOVA_v1`) with `VIRO_v1` in the second file if the first field equals `Software Version` and `ViroHEX` is present anywhere in the 5th column of the first file.

I'm assuming the field separator of the second file is `<space>=<space>` (not a tab).

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution, in my humble opinion. Unfortunately it uses other tools besides awk.

```
awk '{print $5}' A.txt | grep -q VIROHEX && sed 2s/NOVA/VIRO/ B.txt
```

The part before && implements the condition, the `sed` program replaces the text in file B.txt.

EDIT: Thanks, AdminBee, for pointing out that my solution is lazy. Better:

```
awk '{print $5}' A.txt | grep -q VIROHEX && sed '2s/=.*/= VIRO_v1/' B.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [berndbausch's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630875/116858), but being a bit more careful about what we're actually matching and inserting.

```bsh
awk -F '\t' '$5 == "ViroHEX" { found = 1; exit } END { exit !found }' A.txt &&
sed '2 s/=.*/= VIRO_v1/' B.txt
```

This first uses `awk` to determine whether the exact string `ViroHEX` occurs in the fifth tab-delimited field, on any line, in the file `A.txt`.  It does not read more of the file than what is necessary, and exits with an exit status that is later used to conditionally run `sed`.

The `sed` command replaces everything form the first `=` character on the second line of `B.txt` with  the string `= VIRO_v1`.

If the `A.txt` file does not contain `ViroHEX` in the fifth column, no output is produced.

The following variation always produces the `B.txt` file, possibly with a replacement done on the second line:

```bsh
if awk -F '\t' '$5 == "ViroHEX" { found = 1; exit } END { exit !found }' A.txt
then
    sed '2 s/=.*/= VIRO_v1/'
else
    cat
fi <B.txt
```

If you, instead of modifying line 2, want to modify the line saying `Software Version = ...`, then change the expression used in the calls to `sed` into

```
s/^\(Software Version = \).*/\1 VIRO_v1/
```